# STL function like sort

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a function like `std::sort` that instead of sorting in increasing order, sorts in decreasing order?

Comment: @NicolBolas is right, but it's also worth noting that in many cases it's easier to sort normally, and just iterate the result in reverse (from `rbegin` to `rend` instead of `begin` to `end`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin, yeah, I was either iterating `--it` or using `std::reverse`

Comment: @JerryCoffin Really? what's the advantage of that?

Comment: @ViniyoShouta Using `std::reverse` would mean an additional O(N) operation.

Comment: @ChristianRau: Maybe I'm the only one who finds it easier, but when I see a third parameter to `sort`, I'm usually expecting something like a primary/secondary key comparison, so it takes me at least a little extra time to deal with it just being descending order.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Ok, I see. On the other hand iterating in reverse usually means something strange is going on, too (maybe dependencies on previous/following elements or the like). If the range is to be sorted in descending order, actual sorting is conceptually more appropriate. But I guess it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: Since sort is O(n*log(n)), an extra O(n) doesn't change things much. Sometimes clarity is worth the price.

Comment: @DavidHammen Well, in practice it is rarely just about big-O and especially in this case (Ok, in others it might be worth it) there is definitely not enough clarity gained (compared to a simple descending sort or even a reverse iteration) to justify an additional pass shuffling around the data. Of course we shouldn't microoptimize excessively, but neither should we give ourselves dumber than we really are.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. It's called [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

`sort` has an overload that takes a functor that defines the sort order as a third parameter. If you want decreasing order, then pass it [`std::greater<T>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater), where `T` is your type.

Comment: `std::sort( vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::greater<u_int>() );` it is! Thanks, no more `std::reverse` will be written